# No Calendars Sync - iCloud or Google

Tags: icloud, calendar, google-calendar

I have two Macs, and iPhone and iPad. I have setup iCloud and Google accounts with Calendars on all of them. Its works everywhere, syncs and loads up great, except for 1 Mac.

One of them just won't sync any calendars, be it iCloud or Google. I enable the Google Account and then I just get no calendars download and appear.

Any help much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On your Mac that isn't syncing, go to System Preferences > Internet Accounts. From the list of accounts in the left column of the screen, select the account that isn't syncing in. Make sure that "Calendars" is checked.

[image]

Next, open your Calendars app. Click "Calendar" (next to the Apple icon in the menu bar) > Preferences (NOTE: Clicking "Accounts" instead of "Preferences" will just send you back to System Preferences > Internet Accounts). In the Preferences pane, click "Accounts". Select the account that wasn't syncing. Then make sure that "Enable this account" is checked.

[image]

If the calendar still isn't appearing, make sure that you're not hiding the calendar. There is a toggle button in the Calendar app that hides or shows the list of calendars available to display. If you cannot see a list of calendars on the left column of your Calendar app, then click the "Calendars" button in the top left corner of your Calendar app. This will display a list of calendars on the left side of the app. Make sure that your missing calendars are checked. Unchecked calendars will not show up in your calendar view.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't resolve anything. These are basic instructions for displaying your Calendars, not a resolution for ones that are not syncing as in my case.